# How to change hub col from Boolean to string in kdb?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to convert a Boolean col in hdb to string and change its values to something else simultaneously. I used fncol with vector conditional but that changed the col type to char instead of array of chars. What is the best way to go about it?

`fncol [hdbPath;tableName;colName;{?(x=0b;"Y";"N")}]`

Comment: If you want to change it to "Y" and "N" then what's wrong with the column being type char? That's what "Y" and "N" are, and it would be more efficient than strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of possible way to do it. You just need to ensure that each char is enlisted so it is type `10h`

```
q){n:count x;?[x=0b;n#enlist"Y";n#enlist"N"]}001b
,"Y"
,"Y"
,"N"
```

Or:

```
q){enlist each ?[x=0b;"Y";"N"]}001b
,"Y"
,"Y"
,"N"
```

Dictionary lookup:

```
q){(01b!enlist each "YN") x}001b
,"Y"
,"Y"
,"N"
```

Use the fact that booleans index:

```
q){(enlist each "YN") x}001b
,"Y"
,"Y"
,"N"
```

Comment: Thank you! I followed the second method and it worked for me.